# python 2 byte string that are not encoded in utf-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I maintain an api that can gets text input from multiple languages. We would like to make the encoding of string to be in `utf-8`.

Most of the solutions that previous developers have tried involved using the encode and decode function willy nilly. It just leads to confusing unmaintainable code.

For simplicity I am just defining `x` here but lets imagine this can be sent to my api. This string is encoded in `latin-1`

```py
x = '\xe9toile' # x is a byte string in python 2
x.encode('utf-8')
```

results in

```py
*** UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The only way that I know of to encode it to `utf-8` is to first decode it as `latin-1` then do the encoding.

```py
x.decode('latin-1')
>>u'\xe9toile'
(x.decode('latin-1')).encode('utf-8')
>>'\xc3\xa9toile'
```

What if I did not know that the byte string was encoded in `latin-1` how would I be able to encode it to `utf-8` ?

What would I do if  `x` was this chinese encoding that I don't know ?

```
x = '\u54c8\u54c8'
```

`x` is always a byte string. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is a byte string then it doesn't make sense for you to encode it. Text encodings are a way to represent text as bytes. You first have to turn your bytes into text by decoding them and then encode that text into your target encoding.

> What if I did not know that the byte string was encoded in `latin-1` how would I be able to encode it to `utf-8`?

You can try to guess the encoding but you can't always be right:

```
>>> 'Vlh'.encode('cp037')
'\xe5\x93\x88'
>>> '哈'.encode('utf-8')
'\xe5\x93\x88'
```

This example is a little contrived but there's no way to know if the bytes `'\xe5\x93\x88'` represent `哈` or `Vlh` unless you know the original encoding.

The most sensible solution would be to just have your clients encode their text as UTF-8 and then you decode the bytes you receive as UTF-8.